# How to combine textures with depth in modern OpenGL?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm working on a rendering stack and had to render my scene into two textures with depth render buffers. Now to generate the final scene I want to combine those two renders as a texture of a plane with a plain shader. However, I'm struggling to figure out how to use the depth render buffers to combine both textures minding the distance of the objects.

Searching for a solution I found [this](ftp://ftp.sgi.com/opengl/contrib/blythe/advanced99/notes/node118.html), which is an outdated solution, but gave some insights. Anyone knows how to do it in modern OpenGL ES 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's an depth-sensitive overlay of opaque geometry and all you have is two planes of 3D stuff, then all you can do is load samples from both depth textures, compare them to pick the one you want, and then load the color value from the "winner" and write that to the output pixel.

... but it sounds rather expensive and not really getting the value our of a 3D GPU (the entire point of GPUs supporting depth/stencil testing is to avoid this kind of messing about), so not having to merge the two passes would be better if there is any scope for changing your pipeline ...

Comment: Yeah, my idea was to use the depth information that I already have for depth/stencil testing, but I could not figure out how to do it.

Comment: When writing to the main window surface you can't - OpenGL ES doesn't allow you to modify the depth programmatically from shaders. For off-screen rendering just attach the depth texture you want to use to the FBO as a depth attachment, and then just don't clear it.

Comment: Ok, this is helpful, however, I found a solution to my problem using a conditional in the shader instead of rendering two different scenes.